# Python dict with int entries comparison with int?

Tags: python

Good evening! I am trying to figure out how to compare a variable with the int entries in a dictionary. I am programming an arcade game and I have x and y coordinates stored in a dict (x:y) and playerx and playery variables. I would like to make a comparison so that if the player ever reaches coordinates specified in the dict, it would do something. How could I go about doing this?

I imagine something along the lines of:

```
if playerx in dict:
    if playery in dict[x]:
        dosomething()
```

But I cannot quite figure out how to do it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use a list of tuples

```
l_coord = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
player_x = 2
player_y = 3
player = (player_x, player_y)
if player in l_coord:
    print("I am here.")
```

Comment: for x1 in range(0, 1250):
    for y2 in range(0, 700):
        xy12 = disp.get_at((x1, y2))
        if xy12[0] <= 3 and xy12[1] <= 3 and xy12[2] <= 3:
            Pixels.append((x1, y2))

def pglc():
    global groundlim
    if (tuple((playerx, playery))) in Pixels:
        print(tuple((playerx, playery)))
        groundlim -= 1
    else:
        print("No")
        groundlim += 1

Comment: I'm trying this list of tuples, but it returns True almost constantly, so the player just floats upwards. I am so confused as to why it is always True

Comment: Do you want the exact point or a region? If it's True it's because it's there. You need to consider too, that the mouse event it very quick and sometimes give you a lot of info.

Comment: I want character coordinates to check if the player is on a surface that is walk-able in Pygame. The for loops check if there are any black pixels on screen. If the player contacts any black Pixel, I want to make that surface walkable.

Comment: I think the problem may be in how the for loops are formatted. When I print the dict, it only has items at y = 699

Comment: What i think you want is the check if the click is inside an area, but, if you have a list of coordinates of the surface this is the code.

Comment: There is no clicking involved in my pygame program. I want to check if player coords meets the coords of any black pixel on screen. If it does, set that y value as the limit to falling, making it the ground. However, the dict only captures entries where y = 699 and x ranges from 0 to 1250.

Comment: Pixels = {}

for x1 in range(0, 1250):
    for y2 in range(0, 700):
        xy12 = disp.get_at((x1, y2))
        if xy12[0] <= 3 and xy12[1] <= 3 and xy12[2] <= 3:
             Pixels[x1] = y2

def pglc():
    global groundlim
    if playerx in Pixels:
        if playery == Pixels[playerx]:
            groundlim = playery

print Pixels

Comment: When I print pixels it shows that the for loops only added y = 699 to the dict at ranging x values

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you need:

```
player=(0,1)

your_dict = {0:1,1:2,2:3}

if player[0] in your_dict:
    if player[1] == your_dict[player[0]]:
        print("hello, is it me you're looking for?")
```

Answer (score 2):

given the speed of dictionaries its a very fast python data structure. but
if you want to really visualize coordinates intuitively , try creating a **spatial(x,y)** tuple. assuming all locations are managed properly by your game scheme.

```
#Code
d={"VillageLocation":(1,1)}
player1_location=(1,1)
player2_location=(2,2)
#check by values
reachedVillage = player1_location in d.values() #returns True #method for checking by values
if (reachedVillage == True):
    goToSleep("player1")
```

**Explanation**: Player 1 will now go to sleep because player1's location and village location now match which is stored as 'True' in the 
"reachedVillage "variable.

**Trick Used**: checking in dictionary by values instead of keys.